# AngularJS Route Controller Not Reloading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location, routes

I have a very simple AngularJS app that has two routes in it:

```
#/search
#/results
```

When I navigate from one route to another everything works as I'd expected.  Any resources that are needed are fetched and the content is displayed perfectly.

The problem is when I navigate from one route to the same route (I.e., #/results to #/results) absolutely nothing happens.  I understand from the browser's perspective nothing has happened but I'd really like AngularJS to reload the content.

This must be very easy but I'm drawing blanks on this.  Can someone please shed some light on this for me?

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: Do you understand, that if you reload your page, your angular application will just restart?

Comment: The controller should run again, how are you getting your data?

Comment: wait, you mean like you're just going to the address bar and hitting enter? Or you're actually refreshing? Or actually changing the path somehow?

Comment: I have a link on my page that directs my browser to #/results since I'm already there, the browser doesn't do anything.  But I'd expect the routing to detect that and re-load the route?

Comment: Hi Andrey.  Yes I realize that reloading a page that is a single-page-application will restart the application.  I'm not trying to reload the page, merely the one route without having to leave it and come back.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you navigate to the same page, **the browser** ignores it.
Angular.js has nothing to do with the default behavior of `<a href="">`.

What you can do, is to create a **custom directive** which:

- use `$route.reload()` to reload the current view (route).
- use `$location.path(newPath)` for navigating to other views.

I made an [example](http://jsbin.com/OzUTusO/3/edit):

```
app.directive('xref',function($route, $location){
  return {
    link: function(scope, elm,attr){
      elm.on('click',function(){
        if ( $location.path() === attr.xref ) {
          $route.reload();
        } else {
          scope.$apply(function(){
            $location.path(attr.xref);
          });
        }      
      });
    }
  };
});
```

In your view just create:

```
<a xref="/">Home</a>
<a xref="/links">Links</a>
```

Comment: I ended up using this simple directive instead.  So awesome.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the current route is the same as the "destination" route and call `$route`'s **[`reload()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route#methods_reload)** method:

> **reload()**
>   Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location hasn't changed.
>   As a result of that, ngView creates new scope, reinstantiates the controller.

---

E.g.:

**In HTML:**

```
<a href="" ng-click="toResults()">Results</a>
```

**In controller:**

```
// ...first have `$location` and `$route` injected...
$scope.toResults = function () {
    var dstPath = '/results';
    if ($location.path() === dstPath) {
        $route.reload()  ;
    } else {
        $location.path(dstPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That's exactly what I'll do.  Should be easy.

Comment: i have injected $route in my Logout controller but i am getting "[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider <- $route <- LogoutCtrl" issue.Help me out

Comment: Include the `ngRoute` module as a dependency of your app. Everything you need is in thw docs.

Answer (score 0):

I used the routeparams property as well to compare the url parameters and it worked like a charm. In case anyone faces this problem again, here's how I resolved it:

```
 if ($location.path() === '/destination' && $routeParams.Name == Name) {
                $route.reload();
            }
            else {
                $location.path('/destination').search({ Name: Name });
            }
```