# Refreshing/reloading page after logout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want page to be refreshed/reloaded after logout (message on screen is visible for 5 seconds). Current code won't refresh it so I'm still seeing user's name in header instead of something else like Login button.

```
.controller('logout', ['$scope', 'location', 'config', 'auth', '$timeout', '$route', function($scope, location, config, auth, $timeout, $route) {
    auth.isValid($scope, function() {
        auth.logout(function() {
            $timeout(function() {
                location.path('/login');
                $route.reload();
            }, 5000);
        });
    });
}])
```

I've checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs) but nothing changes.

Comment: FYI it's `$location`.

Comment: OK thanks, updated accordingly. Still waiting for the solution though.

Comment: Refer to `Ilan Frumer's` answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125914/angularjs-route-controller-not-reloading

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScript location for this.

location.reload();